# Where was the well situated and how did it flow in the desert?

Tags: water, dor-hamidbar

Many tried to picture the Israelite Camp in the wilderness, but none include the well.
[image: Tent Camps Of The Twelve Tribes Of Israel Arranged by Jan Luyken And Willem Goeree by Jan Luyken]

(c)<sub>Tent Camps Of The Twelve Tribes Of Israel Arranged by Jan Luyken And Willem Goeree by Jan Luyken</sub>

Where was the well situated, how did it flow and what tribes/families did it divide?

Comment: According to Midrash, it was Miriam's well and it traveled with them wherever they went. Of course, Midrash leaves things to the imagination, in a sense. But, here, logically, if Israel were travelling, how could they rely on a single well unless this "well" travelled with them miraculously?

Comment: A well has to flow somewhere??? That doesn't sound like a well to me. Sounds like a reservoir or a lake.

Comment: See Rashi to Bamidbar 21:20 ד"ה ומבמות.